# Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

The basic multivariable Taylor expansion formula around a point is as follows:

$$
f(\mathbf r + \mathbf a) = f(\mathbf r) + (\mathbf a \cdot \nabla )f(\mathbf r) + \frac{1}{2!}(\mathbf a \cdot \nabla)^2 f(\mathbf r) + \cdots
\tag{1}$$

In *Mathematica*, as far as I know, there is only one function, `Series` that deals with Taylor expansion. And this function surprisingly doesn't expand functions in the way the above multivariable Taylor expansion formula does. What I mean is that the function `Series` doesn't produce a Taylor series truncated at the right order.

For example, if I want to expand $f(x,y)$ around $(0,0)$ to order $2$, I think I should evaluate the following *Mathematica* expression:

```
Normal[Series[f[x,y],{x,0,2},{y,0,2}]]
```

But the result also gives order $3$ and order $4$ terms. Of course, I can write the expression in the following way to get a series truncated at order $2$:

```
Normal[Series[f[x,y],{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]]
```

but in this way I lose terms like $x^2$ and $y^2$, so it is still not right.

The formula $(1)$ gives each order in each term, so if the function `Series` would expand a function in the way formula $(1)$ does, there will be no problem.

I am disappointed that the *Mathematica* developers designed `Series` as they did. Does anyone know how to work around this problem?

Comment: TLDR version: The OP does not have a problem with Series in Mathematica but with a Taylor series is to begin with. Series is giving the expected Taylor series. What the OP wants is a Taylor series in two variables under the additional assumption x~y. This additional assumption can easily be implemented by substituting x=t*X and y=t*Y and taking a series in t instead. Note that it is a good thing that Series in Mathematica does not work like this by default because very often this would not be desired and would be very unexpected behavior for a multivariate Taylor series.

Comment: Discussion on wolfram community -- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2353053?p_p_auth=8FpuUkxs

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It's true that the multivariable version of `Series` can't be used for your purpose, but it's still pretty straightforward to get the desired order by introducing a dummy variable `t` as follows:

```
Normal[Series[f[(x - x0) t + x0, (y - y0) t + y0], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
```

> $(x-\text{x0}) (y-\text{y0})
>    f^{(1,1)}(\text{x0},\text{y0})+\frac{1}{2}
>    (x-\text{x0})^2
>    f^{(2,0)}(\text{x0},\text{y0})+(x-\text{x0})
>    f^{(1,0)}(\text{x0},\text{y0})+(y-\text{y0})
>    f^{(0,1)}(\text{x0},\text{y0})+\frac{1}{2}
>    (y-\text{y0})^2
>    f^{(0,2)}(\text{x0},\text{y0})+f(\text{x0},\text{y
>    0})$

The expansion is done only with respect to `t` which is then set to `1` at the end. This guarantees that you'll get exactly the terms up to the total order (`2` in this example) that you specify.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your solution is elegant. simple and general.

Comment: Does this trick work in this way for any expansion order?

Comment: @granularbastard Yes, it does.

Answer (score 32):

Here's an attempt:

```
multiTaylor[f_, {vars_?VectorQ, pt_?VectorQ, n_Integer?NonNegative}] :=
                   Sum[Nest[(vars - pt).# &, (D[f, {vars, \[FormalK]}]
                       /. Thread[vars -> pt]), \[FormalK]]/\[FormalK]!,
                       {\[FormalK], 0, n}, Method -> "Procedural"]

multiTaylor[f[x, y], {{x, y}, {0, 0}, 2}]
   f[0, 0] + y*Derivative[0, 1][f][0, 0] + x*Derivative[1, 0][f][0, 0] +
   (y*(y*Derivative[0, 2][f][0, 0] + x*Derivative[1, 1][f][0, 0]) +
    x*(y*Derivative[1, 1][f][0, 0] + x*Derivative[2, 0][f][0, 0]))/2
```

Comment: I admire your mathematica skill. Your answer is right. But I think the following Jens's solution is better, it is simple and more enlightening.  What do you think? Thank you all the same!!

Comment: No problem; you should always pick the answer that is most helpful to **you** and give that answer the acceptance, after all. I wanted to write something a bit more general (i.e. something that can also handle three, four... variables), so mine is a little bit complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the function – it's very useful to me. One slight problem I just noticed occurs when `f` contains the variable `k`, which will be replaced by some integer after the expansion. To improve you function, you might want to wrap it in `Module[{k}, (* function code *)]` to protect the local variable.

Comment: @David, you're right; I'll incorporate the fix later. Thank you!

Comment: This function should be implemented in Mathematica

Answer (score 22):

Jens answered this nicely. But my preferred way of thinking about this question is via *re-scaling* (essentially using perturbation theory) instead of dummy variables.

For example, to generate the series expansion, re-scale all variables by *s* and expand by series coercion:

```
(f[x,y] /. Thread[{x,y} -> s {x,y}]) + O[s]^3
```

[image: TraditionalForm output]

This form is generally useful—and although one can use Normal, often working with the series is what you really end up wanting to do.

Comment: Thank you so much! O[s] is doing like magic. I am wondering how `O` is defined, it behaves not like a normal function.

Comment: Not magic. If you add a function to a series expansion, the only way for it to make sense is to _automatically_ coerce the function into a series (about the same expansion point).

Comment: If you add 1.0 to Pi, what you would expect should happen. You might consider this to be "magic" too but surely such automatic coercion is what you want to happen...

Comment: Finally, I should have pointed out that `Series` automatically generates `O`. For example, if you enter `Series[f[x],{x,0,3}]` then you'll see `O[x]` in the output.

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility is to strip the "too high" terms with a rule:

```
ser = Series[f[x, y], {x, x0, 2}, {y, y0, 2}];
Normal[ser] /.
 Derivative[m__][f][args__] /; Plus[m] > 2 :> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If `f` is dependent on a variable `k`, the above definition leads to a conflict. It is better to rename `k` in a less common name such as `var`.

```
multiTaylor[f_, {vars_?VectorQ, pt_?VectorQ, n_Integer?NonNegative}] :=
                   Sum[Nest[(vars - pt).# &, (D[f, {vars, var}] /. Thread[vars -> pt]),var]/var!,
                       {var, 0, n}, Method -> "Procedural"]
```