# InverseSeries of multiple variables and multiple equations

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, series-expansion

**CONTEXT**

Let us consider a bit of the Universe in which we draw spheres
[image]

(see a high resolution image [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/659996/simu-500.jpg)). Astronomers have shown that the density within these spheres
could be predicted quite accurately: here is the measured (in red) and predicted (in green) distribution of the density within $50^3$ such spheres at half the age of the Universe:
[image].

Our next purpose is to extend the theory to concentric two or more shells.

In practice, in order to estimate the mildly nonlinear cosmic density of the Universe within
concentric shells,
I need to find perturbatively the [Legendre Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) of a function of two variables
in a singular regime (see below).

> $$\phi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)={\rm LT}(\psi(\rho_1,\rho_2))\equiv \sup_{\rho_1,\rho_2}\left[\lambda_1 \rho_1+\lambda_2 \rho_2-\psi(\rho_1,\rho_2)\right]$$

which in turns involves inverting the system
$$\partial_\rho \psi =\lambda \quad \quad \quad (1) $$
for $\rho_1,\rho_2$ , and integrating for $\phi(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ the system 
$$ \quad \partial_\lambda \phi =\rho \,. \quad \quad (2)  $$
This can in principle be done perturbatively.
In my context, it needs to be done in the regime 
where ${\rm det}| \partial^2_\rho \psi|=0$. I.e. I am interested 
in Taylor expanding the Legendre transform of $\psi$ near 
a point (chosen to be zero for simplicity) where one of the eigenvalues of $\partial^2_\rho \psi$ is zero.
In physical terms it corresponds to the rare event tail of the 
density of the Universe in these shells, if you care to know!

**ATEMPT**

Following [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23280/calculating-taylor-polynomial-of-an-implicit-function-given-by-an-equation/23288#23288) 
 I know how to do invert (1) for $\rho(\lambda)$ in 1D (one shell) for the *regular*

```
 nn = 3;
 ρofλr = InverseSeries[Series[ψ'[ρ], {ρ, 0,nn}]] /. ρ -> λ /. ψ'[0] -> 0 /. 
   Derivative[n_][ψ][0] :>  Subscript[ψ, n] // Normal
```

[image: reg]

(note the division by `ψ''[0]`)

and the *singular* case (for which `ψ''[0]=0`)

```
 nn = 3;
  ρofλs = InverseSeries[Series[ψ'[ρ], {ρ, 0,nn}]/. ψ''[0]-> 0] /. ρ -> λ /. ψ'[0] -> 0 /. 
    Derivative[n_][ψ][0] :>  Subscript[ψ, n] // Normal
```

[image: reg]

note the square root. It is clear from this expansion that the Legendre 
transform, `ϕ[λ]` will have a very different algebraic form in the singular case
compared to the regular case.

```
 ϕ[λ_]=Integrate[ρofλ,λ]
```

But this is not enough for concentric shells: I need to be able to carry out such
Legendre transform when one coordinate is singular.

**SOLUTION to first order and for the regular case only**

The following works for the regular case only.
Let us expand the first system

```
   nn=1;
   eqn = Thread[{λ1, λ2} == 
   Series[{Derivative[1, 0][ψ][ ρ1,  ρ2], 
   Derivative[0, 1][ψ][ ρ1,  ρ2]}, { ρ1, 0, 
   nn}, { ρ2, 0, nn}]] // Normal;
```

and reoder it in power of `ϵ`

```
  eqn2 = eqn /. 
  Derivative[i_, j_][ψ][0, 
   0] -> ϵ^(i + j - 1) Derivative[i, j][ψ][0, 0] // 
 Series[#, {ϵ, 0, 1}] & // Simplify;
```

Solve for `ρ1,ρ2`

```
 sol = Solve[Normal[eqn2], { ρ1,  ρ2}][[1]] /. 
 Derivative[n_, p_][ψ][__] :>  Subscript[ψ, n, p] // 
 FullSimplify;
```

We can then integrate the system (2):

```
 eqn3 = {D[ϕ[λ1, λ2], λ1] == ρ1,D[ϕ[λ1, λ2], λ2] ==  ρ2} /. sol
 ϕ[λ1, λ2]/. DSolve[eqn3,ϕ[λ1, λ2], {λ1, λ2}][[1, 1]] // Apart
```

[image]

But this is not good enough because I am interested in a singular expansion, 
i.e. near  a point where the Jacobian $\partial^2 \psi \partial \rho_i \partial \rho_j$
has zero determinant! (when the above first order solution becomes singular
because `ψ02 ψ20 -ψ11^2 =0`)

**QUESTION**

> I am interested in doing this in 2D (or 3D...) for  the singular case,
>   i.e. when the Jacobian $\partial^2_\rho \psi$ has one null eigenvalue.

The  main difficulty is that `InverseSeries` does not work for series of two variables.

The gist of the problem is the following: assuming `x1`, `x2` `y1` and `y2` are small,
how does one invert pertubatively

```
 y1= x1+ x1^2 + x2^2 + x1 x2 + x2^3...
 y2= x2^2 + x1^2 +x1 x2 + x1^3 +...
```

in order to write

```
 x1= y1+...
 x2= sqrt(y2)+...
```

This might sound like a technical question, but the core of the problem is 
fairly general: **how does one `InverseSeries` of multiple variables and multiple equations?** in Mathematica. Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: _"The mildly nonlinear cosmic density of the Universe within concentric shells"_  has been estimated a few years ago :)http://www.sacred-texts.com/astro/cwiu/img/00700.jpg

Comment: well yes I guess I want to revisit this expansion :-)

Comment: In the help for `Series` it says that when dealing with multivariable series, it "successively finds series expansions with respect to x, then y, etc." So if you want to invert this process, maybe you could attack it by using `InverseSeries` one variable at a time.

Comment: the pb is that the ordering of the series in not one variable at a time(?)

Comment: In general, one would invert with the linear term. If that's zero, then you'd invert with the quadratic. If that's singular, then on to the cubic. So maybe the thing to do in your case is write out that cubic term.

Comment: I agree with the strategy: this is what I do in 1D. The question is how to carry out these steps in 2D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Algebraically, the way to construct the inverse of a series is straightforward.  The basic iterative step is to add the next degree terms and solve for the coefficients.

If we have $u = U(x, y)$, $v = V(x, y)$, then we are looking for $x = X(u, v)$, $y = Y(u, v)$ such that $u = U(X(u,v), Y(u,v))$ and $v = V(X(u,v), Y(u,v))$ identically.  If the coefficients of the partial series
$$
 X_n(u,v) = \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^k a_{i,k-i} u^i v^{k-i}, \quad 
 Y_n(u,v) = \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^k b_{i,k-i} u^i v^{k-i}
$$
have been determined, then plug
$$
 x = X_n(u,v) + \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} a_{i,n+1-i} u^i v^{n+1-i}, \quad 
 y = Y_n(u,v) + \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} b_{i,n+1-i} u^i v^{n+1-i}
$$
into
$$
u = U(X(u,v), Y(u,v)), \quad v = V(X(u,v), Y(u,v))
$$
and set the coefficients of the monomials $u^iv^j$ to zero and solve for the
unknown $a$ and $b$.

That's the inductive step, more or less, but how to get started?  The original question assumes (justifiably -- by a translation, if necessary) that $(0,0)$ is mapped to $(0,0)$.  If the linear terms form an invertible system, then the inductive step can be applied repeatedly up to the desired degree.  In the case of the question, the assumptions are that the linear system is nonzero but degenerate ($U_x \ne 0$, $U_y=0$) and the second order system is parabolic, aligned in an independent direction ($U_{yy}(0,0) \ne 0$, $U_{xx}=U_{xy}=0$).  In this case, the solutions will be power series in $u$, $\sqrt{v}$.

The function `series2DSolveParabolic` constructs the series solution up to whatever degree desired.  Notes on the code can be found below the example.

```
terms[poly_, deg_, vars_] := FromCoefficientRules[
   Select[CoefficientRules[poly, vars], Total@First@# <= deg &], vars];

series2D[series2DData[f_, {x_, y_}, dataRules_], n_] := 
  terms[Normal@Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}] /. dataRules, 
    n, {x, y}];
series2D[series2DSolData[a_, {u_, v_}], n_] := Sum[u^i*v^(-i + k)*a[i, -i + k],
  {k, 1, n}, {i, 0, k}];

solveCoeff[terms_, pat_] := Solve[Thread[terms == 0], Cases[terms, pat, Infinity]];

series2DSolveParabolic[{u_ == U0_series2DData, v_ == V0_series2DData}, {x_, y_}, deg_] :=
  Module[{a, b, X0, Y0, r},
   a[0, 0] = b[0, 0] = 0;
   X0 = series2DSolData[a, {u, r}];
   Y0 = series2DSolData[b, {u, r}];
   Do[
    solveCoeff[
      DeleteCases[
       Flatten[CoefficientList[#, {u, r}] & /@ {
          u - terms[series2D[U0, n] /.
            {x -> series2D[X0, n], y -> series2D[Y0, n]}, n, {u, r}],
          r^2 - terms[series2D[V0, n + 1] /.
            {x -> series2D[X0, n + 1], y -> series2D[Y0, n + 1]}, n + 1, {u, r}]}],
       _?NumericQ], _a | _b] /. Rule -> Set,
    {n, 1, deg}];

   {x -> Sum[a[i, j - i] u^i v^((j - i)/2), {j, 0, deg}, {i, 0, j}],
    y -> Sum[b[i, j - i] u^i v^((j - i)/2), {j, 0, deg}, {i, 0, j}]}
   ];
```

Example (a bit messy):

```
    series2DSolveParabolic[
     {u == series2DData[U, {x, y}, {U[0, 0] -> 0, Derivative[0, 1][U][0, 0] -> 0}],
      v == series2DData[V, {x, y},
        {V[0, 0] -> 0, Derivative[1, 0][V][0, 0] -> 0, 
         Derivative[0, 1][V][0, 0] -> 0, 
         Derivative[1, 1][V][0, 0] -> 0, 
         Derivative[2, 0][V][0, 0] -> 0}]},
        {x, y}, 2]

(* {x -> u/Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0] -
         (v*Derivative[0, 2][U][0, 0])/
           (Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0] * Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0]) -
         (Sqrt[2]*u*Sqrt[v] * Derivative[1, 1][U][0, 0]) /
           (Sqrt[Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0]] * Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0]^2) -
         (u^2 * Derivative[2, 0][U][0, 0]) / (2*Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0]^3), 
   y -> (Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[v]) / Sqrt[Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0]] -
         (v * Derivative[0, 3][V][0, 0]) / (3*Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0]^2) -
         (u * Sqrt[v]*Derivative[1, 2][V][0, 0]) / 
           (Sqrt[2]*Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0]^(3/2) * Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0]) -
         (u^2*Derivative[2, 1][V][0, 0]) /
           (2 * Derivative[0, 2][V][0, 0]*Derivative[1, 0][U][0, 0]^2)}  *)
```

$$\left\{x\to -\frac{u^2 U^{(2,0)}(0,0)}{2
   U^{(1,0)}(0,0)^3}-\frac{\sqrt{2} u \sqrt{v}
   U^{(1,1)}(0,0)}{U^{(1,0)}(0,0)^2
   \sqrt{V^{(0,2)}(0,0)}}+\frac{u}{U^{(1,0)}(0,0
   )}-\frac{v U^{(0,2)}(0,0)}{U^{(1,0)}(0,0)
   V^{(0,2)}(0,0)}\right.,$$
$$\left.y\to -\frac{u^2
   V^{(2,1)}(0,0)}{2 U^{(1,0)}(0,0)^2
   V^{(0,2)}(0,0)}-\frac{u \sqrt{v}
   V^{(1,2)}(0,0)}{\sqrt{2} U^{(1,0)}(0,0)
   V^{(0,2)}(0,0)^{3/2}}-\frac{v
   V^{(0,3)}(0,0)}{3
   V^{(0,2)}(0,0)^2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}
   \sqrt{v}}{\sqrt{V^{(0,2)}(0,0)}}\right\}$$

Notes on the code:

`terms[poly, deg, vars]` -- return the terms of the polynomial whose total degree is at most `deg`

`series2DData[f, {x, y}, dataRules]` -- represents a series in the variables `x` and `y`, with  conditions on the derivatives of  `f` given in `dataRules`

`series2DSolData[c, {x, y},]` -- represents a series in the variables `x` and `y` with  coefficients `c[i, j]`.

`series2D[ser, n]` -- returns the `n`-th degree Taylor polynomial of the series `ser`; `ser` may be either `series2DData` or `series2DSolData`

`solveCoeff[terms, pat]` -- sets the terms equal to zero and solves for the coefficients represented by the pattern `pat`.

`series2DSolveParabolic[{u == uSeries, v == vSeries}, vars, deg]` solves the system of equations for power series of `vars` in terms of  the variables `{u, v}` up to degree `deg`.  Note that the equation are not really treated as equations. The variables `u` and `v` have to be symbols and be the left-hand sides.  Note also that internally in the `Do` loop, `r` represents `Sqrt[v]`, and that the exponent is off by one (goes up to `n+1`); this has to do with the recursive procedure starting with degree 1 in `x` and degree 2 in `y`.

---

Here's a function that will invert power series if the linear terms are nonsingular.

```
series2DSolve[{u_ == U0_series2DData, v_ == V0_series2DData}, {x_, y_}, deg_] :=
  Module[{a, b, X0, Y0},
   a[0, 0] = b[0, 0] = 0;
   X0 = series2DSolData[a, {u, v}];
   Y0 = series2DSolData[b, {u, v}];
   Do[
    solveCoeff[
      DeleteCases[
       Flatten[CoefficientList[#, {u, v}] & /@ {
          u -> terms[series2D[U0, n] /. {x -> series2D[X0, n], y -> series2D[Y0, n]},
                 n, {u, v}],
          v -> terms[series2D[V0, n] /. {x -> series2D[X0, n], y -> series2D[Y0, n]},
                 n, {u, v}]}],
        _?NumericQ], _a | _b] /. 
     Rule -> Set,
    {n, 1, deg}];

   {x -> Sum[a[i, j - i] u^i v^(j - i), {j, 0, deg}, {i, 0, j}],
    y -> Sum[b[i, j - i] u^i v^(j - i), {j, 0, deg}, {i, 0, j}]}
   ];
```

Example

```
f[x_, y_] := Log[1 + x];
g[x_, y_] := Sin[y];
series2DSolve[
 {u == series2DData[f, {x, y}, {}],
  v == series2DData[g, {x, y}, {}]},
 {x, y}, 5]
  (* {x -> u + u^2/2 + u^3/6 + u^4/24 + u^5/120, y -> v + v^3/6 + (3 v^5)/40} *)

Normal@Series[ArcSin[v], {v, 0, 6}]
  (* v + v^3/6 + (3 v^5)/40 *)
```

---

The methods used are from basic algebra.  There could be, there ought to be, or perhaps there are built-in functions to do some or all of the above.

Comment: Brilliant! I need to check a few things before granting the bounty. If you want non-anonymous credits in the scientific publication I ll need to know who you really are :-)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a full answer, but it's too long to fit in the comment box. It sounds like what you want is a Taylor series in 2D. Wikipedia gives this:

[image]

In order to apply this in your case, you would need to specify the point {a,b} about which you are expanding. Presumably your f[a,b]=0 and the first derivative terms are also zero, so you would look at the squared terms. If this is also zero, then you go to the higher terms (which are also written out at wikipedia).

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279585/taylor-series-for-functions-frn-rightarrow-rn) a place where the vector version is stated, in this formulation, f can be a function from $R^2$ to $R^2$. This is the case you have since you have two input variables and two output varables.

Comment: That's the starting point. One has two such expansions, say $f$ and $g$ and we want $x=x(f,g)$ and $y=y(f,g)$ in the regime where $f_x(a,b)=0$.