# Inverting series with symbolic coefficients?

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion, inverse

I am trying to invert the series symbolically. Is this possible in Mathematica?

*Example 1 -*

Let $p = u + au^2 + bu^3$, where $a,b$ are symbolic variables. I am trying to invert the series around $u=0$ say up to $4$ th order. That is I am trying to get inverse series in terms of $p$ with coefficients in terms of $a,b$.

How do we manage this once we have two dimensional case?

*Example 2 -*

Suppose we have 
$$p = u + au^2 + b uv + cv^2$$
$$q = v + dv^2 + euv+ fv^2$$

I am trying to invert the series say upto $4$th order. That is I am trying to get the inverse series in terms of $p,q$.
Like $$u = ()p + ()p^2 + ()q + ()q^2 + ()pq + \ldots$$
$$v = ()p + ()p^2 + ()q + ()pq + ()q^2 + \ldots$$, where the coefficients are in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.

I was trying **Inverse Series** $[u + a u^2 + b u^3 , p]$ but seems like it is not working.

I tried defining a function like $f[u] = u + au^2 + bu^3$ and then using the inverse series Inverse Series$[f[u],p]$. Seems this is also not working.

Any help?

EDIT - 
Trying Carl Woll suggestions, still I am making mistake somewhere -

```
asymptoticSolve[args__] := CloudEvaluate[System`AsymptoticSolve[args]]
asymptoticSolve[{p == u + a u^2 + b u v + c v^2, 
  q == v + d u^2 + e u v + f v^2}, {{u, v}, {0, 0}}, {{p, q}, {0, 0}, 
  3}]
```

results into output

```
CloudEvaluate[
 AsymptoticSolve[{p == {u + u^2 + u v + c v^2, 
     u + 2 u^2 + 2 u v + c v^2, u + 3 u^2 + 3 u v + c v^2}, 
   q == d u^2 + v + e u v + v^2 Function[x, 4 x (1 - x)]}, {{u, 
    v}, {0, 0}}, {{p, q}, {0, 0}, 3}]]
```

Not sure why?

Comment: This, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202126/simple-solvey-5-2-x-xa-x-not-working/202201#202201 and this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation (see the answer of Pietro Majer) is relevant.

Comment: For the first example add order term `O[u]^4` and then use `InverseSeries[u + a u^2 + b u^3 + O[u]^4, p]`.

Comment: Try, `InverseSeries[Series[u + a u^2 + b u^3, {u, 0, 10}]]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InverseSeries of multiple variables and multiple equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24871/inverseseries-of-multiple-variables-and-multiple-equations)

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and answers, seem really helpful. will try to go through them, seems like this is a duplicate question, but still  I am not sure, I request some time before the question is marked duplicate,. Thanks!

Comment: Do `Clear[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and then try again.

Comment: Yes thanks! now it works! may be I had declared some varibales a,b,c,d I see the unknown 4x(1-x) coming there! This works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) for this:

```
AsymptoticSolve[
    {
    p == u + a u^2 + b u v + c v^2,
    q == v + d v^2 + e u v + f v^2
    }, 
    {{u, v}, {0, 0}},
    {{p, q}, {0, 0}, 3}
]
```

> {{u -> p - a p^2 + 2 a^2 p^3 - b p q + (3 a b + b e) p^2 q - 
>       c q^2 + (b^2 + 2 a c + b d + 2 c e + b f) p q^2 + (b c + 2 c d + 
>          2 c f) q^3, 
>     v -> q - e p q + (a e + e^2) p^2 q + (-d - f) q^2 + (b e + 3 d e + 
>          3 e f) p q^2 + (2 d^2 + c e + 4 d f + 2 f^2) q^3}}

Comment: There are several branches of u and v as functions of p and q. Does AsymptoticSolve take it into account?

Comment: @user64494 The short answer is yes. If there are multiple branches, [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) will return multiple results. You can control which branch is being inverted by specifying an expansion point in the second argument of [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) as I did, although there may still be multiple roots in this case.

Comment: Thank you. However, the command AsymptoticSolve[p == u + a*u^2 + b*u^3, {u, 0}, {p, 0, 3}] performs only {{u -> p - a p^2 + (2 a^2 - b) p^3}}.

Comment: @user64494 AsymptoticSolve is returning the only solution that passes through $u=0$ and $p=0$. If you want multiple branches, don't specify $u=0$, i.e., ``AsymptoticSolve[p == u + a u^2 + b u^3, u, {p, 0, 3}]``.

Comment: Seems like this is much helpful, but I am not sure why I am getting this output when I use asymptotic solve, any comments? I am getting output as: 
 AsymptoticSolve[{p == {u + u^2 + u v + c v^2, 
    u + 2 u^2 + 2 u v + c v^2, u + 3 u^2 + 3 u v + c v^2}, 
  q == v + e u v + d v^2 + v^2 Function[x, 4 x (1 - x)]}, {{u, v}, {0,
    0}}, {{p, q}, {0, 0}, 3}]

Comment: i am unaware of writing it in code style, sorry.

Comment: @BAYMAX As I said, it is a new in M12 function. Are you using M12? If not, you could try using the cloud by defining ``asymptoticSolve[args__] := CloudEvaluate[System`AsymptoticSolve[args]]``, and then using `asymptoticSolve` instead of `AsymptoticSolve`.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWoll still can you please see the edit to the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, the result of AsymptoticSolve[p == u + a u^2 + b u^3, u, {p, 0, 3}] is a complicated ConditionalExpression depending on  the sign of -a^2 Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b] + (a^2 - 4 b)^(3/2) + 4 Sqrt[a^2 - 4 b] b. That result is not in accordance with the results of my answer. I think Solve makes nonequivalent transforms and Reduce doesn't.

Comment: @user64494 Why do you think the answers disagree? If I feed some numbers in, e.g., `{a->3, b->10}` and FullSimplify your result, it agrees with mine. Can you find values of a and b where the results disagree?

Answer (score 2):

### Example 1

Let's define series like this:

```
p[u_] := u + a u^2 + b u^3 + O[u]^4
```

Inversing series `p` gives:

```
q[x_] := Evaluate[InverseSeries[p[x], x]];
q[p]
```

> $p-a p^2+p^3 \left(2 a^2-b\right)+O\left(p^4\right)$

Check that q is an inverse  series for p:

```
q[p[u]]
```

> $u+O\left(u^4\right)$

### Example 2

I believe the solution that you are looking for is documented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25111/67461).

Comment: You wrote "I believe the solution that you are looking for is documented here". If I am not mistaken, there are no parameters in the latest example by @Michael E2.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider your example 1 (I think example 2 can be done in future versions of Mathematica only.). There are several cases depending on parameters and four branches of `u` as a function of `p` up to the result of

```
s = Reduce[p == u + a*u^2 + b*u^3, u] // ToRadicals
```

> (b != 0 && (u == -(a/(3 b)) - (2^(1/3) (-a^2 + 3 b))/(
>          3 b (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>             4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(
>           1/3)) + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>            4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(1/3)/(
>          3 2^(1/3) b) || 
>        u == -(a/(3 b)) + ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-a^2 + 3 b))/(
>          3 2^(2/3)
>            b (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>             4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(
>           1/3)) - ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>             4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(1/3))/(
>          6 2^(1/3) b) || 
>        u == -(a/(3 b)) + ((1 - I Sqrt[3]) (-a^2 + 3 b))/(
>          3 2^(2/3)
>            b (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>             4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(
>           1/3)) - ((1 + I Sqrt[3]) (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p + Sqrt[
>             4 (-a^2 + 3 b)^3 + (-2 a^3 + 9 a b + 27 b^2 p)^2])^(1/3))/(
>          6 2^(1/3) b))) || (b == 0 && a == 0 && u == p) || (b == 0 && 
>      a != 0 && (u == (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 4 a p])/(2 a) || 
>        u == (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 a p])/(2 a)))

Let us consider the first case and the first branch. Then

```
Series[Part[s[[1, 2, 1]], 2], {p, 0, 4}]
```

does the job (A long output is omitted.).

Comment: Since you are concerned by the multiple solutions branches, you may be interested to look at this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98467/how-can-i-get-the-solutions-of-xn-x-t-0-in-hypergeometric-form by @ChipHurst , which uses series expansion of the `Root` object.

Comment: @yarchik: Thank you for a useful reference.

Comment: You would get much simpler answers if you don't use `ToRadicals`.