# Series expansion for small ratio of variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I have a messy expression of variables that I would like to simplify under the assumption that  certain ratios of the variables are small.  For example, consider $\sqrt{x+y}\;$ expanded for small $\frac{y}{x}$. That is, $x >> y$. This is simple enough to do by hand (pull out a $\sqrt{x}$ and then  define a new variable to be $\frac{y}{x}$, then expand this variable about $0$). But, I cannot figure out how to do it in *Mathematica*.

**EDIT 1**

I've since realized that what I actually want to do is more complicated than the example above.  Consider the following expression $\sqrt{a+d} + \sqrt{b+d}\;$ expanded for small $\frac{d}{a}$ and small $\frac{d}{b}$ (that is $a>>d$ and $b>>d$).  Following Artes' answer below, the solution is

```
Series[ (a + d)^(1/2) + (b + d)^(1/2) /. {d -> z1 a, d -> z2}, {z1, 0, 2},{z2, 0, 2}] /. 
{z1 -> d/a, z2 -> d/b}
```

But this solution doesn't work as intended due to the order operations *Mathematica* performs upon this command.  What needs to be done is to replace `d` with `z1 a`, then expand `z1` about `0`, replace `z1` with `d/a`, then replace `d` with `z2 b`, expand `z2` about `0`, and finally replace `z2` with `d/b`.  How can one do this in *Mathematica*?
(Obviously the example I gave can be separated into two expressions when can be expanded separately, but this cannot be done for the more complicated expression I am actually trying to expand).

Comment: If this example can be simply worked out as you've observed then it won't be an appropriate one to present the issue. Try to provide another example which might be better suited for your real problem. You shouldn't use `0.5` since it means (in `Mathematica`) a machine precission number unlike `1/2` denoting an exact value.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, this is a possible duplicate of [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected). There are some practical differences, but I think they are very minor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are options in `Series` (`Analytic`, `Assumptions`) which you might exploit. Nonetheless let's use a bit more straightforward approach, simply change the variable `y` (`y -> z x`) and then back `z -> y/x`:

```
Series[(x + y)^(1/2) /. y -> z x, {z, 0, 5}] /. z -> y/x // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**Edit**

Since the question has been edited we should add a few remarks.
In order to transform appropriately  the `Series` results  (its head is `SeriesData`) we should get rid of it with `Normal` (then we loose terms with powers `(y/x)`), e.g.

```
Normal @ Series[(x + y)^(1/2) /. y -> z x, {z, 0, 5}] /. z -> y/x // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Nonetheless we can transform appropriately expressions of the form `(a + d)^(1/2) + (b + d)^(1/2)` working with `SeriesData` if we define a simple function, e.g.

```
f[x_, y_, k_] := Series[(x + y)^k /. y -> z x, {z, 0, 5}] /. z -> y/x

(a + d)^(1/2) + (b + d)^(1/2) /. (x_ + y_)^k_ -> f[x, y, k] // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Alternatively we can expand a given expression around infinity, e.g.

```
Series[(a + d)^(1/2) + (b + d)^(1/2) /. {a -> v d, b -> w d},
       {v, Infinity, 5}, {w, Infinity, 5}] /.
{v -> a/ d, w -> b/d} // Quiet // TraditionalForm
```

Comment: much simpler than what I use, +1.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense.  What if I have many ratio's I want to expand about?  My expression is a function of a,b,c,d,e,f and I want to write it as an expansion for d,e,f << a,b,c.  Is it valid to use ReplaceAll in steps?  That is, first replace d with d/a, expand, then replace d with d/b, expand, etc... for each d,e,f.  I could do this with a loop, obviously, but each Series expansion is already slow enough.  Is there a way to do it using a similar method as your answer above?

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for an upvote.

Comment: @mcFreid You could use just once `ReplaceAll` e.g. `Series[...]/.{z1->d/a,z2->e/b,z3->f/c}` and then change variables back. There are in 99% cases better ways than loops in `Mathematica`.

Comment: So there's no issue with Series[expr /. {d -> z1 a, d -> z2 b, d -> z3 c, e -> z4 a, e -> z5 b, e -> z6 c, f -> z7 a, f -> z8 b, f -> z9 c}] /.  {z1 -> d/a, z2 -> d/b, etc...} ?

Comment: @mcFreid Keep in mind that you should appropriately include in `Series` where an expression `expr` should be expanded, what variables to use and how many terms you need, e.g. ` Series[expr /. listOfRules, {{z1, 0, 5}, {z2, 0, 3}, {z3, 0, 5}}]/.listOfReciprocalRules // Quiet`.

Comment: Yup - just didn't put that in the question above.  Sorry for the confusion.  How does Mathematica handle the command?  Ideally it would try (d -> z1 a), expand z1 about 0, apply (z1 -> d/a), then try (d -> z2 b) and go on.  From the ordering of the code though, my feeling is that this would not be the case and instead it would never get to (d -> z2 b) because after (d -> z1 a) there are no d's left.

Comment: @mcFreid If you are not sure you've got a correct answer you should better wait a bit and then choose the best one to accept it. My experience is that one needs a certain well defined expression to work with and to provide the best possible solution. You can edit you question providing your (appropriately small) expression which might be a good example for any possible issues. Then I (or someone else) could add an answer which completely clarifies your problem.

Comment: I clarified my questions as requested.

Comment: @mcFreid So what, does the answer satisfy your needs now?