# nested series expansion

Tags: functions, series-expansion

I have to invert the following matrix in which the functions `U[t,x,y,r]` and `K[t,x,y,r]` and all their derivatives are "small";

```
matr={{(1 - 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2 - 2*D[K[t, x, y, r], t]/c), -D[
    K[t, x, y, r], x], -D[K[t, x, y, r], y], -D[K[t, x, y, r], 
    r]}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], x], -(1 + 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2), 0, 
  0}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], y], 0, -(1 + U[t, x, y, r]/c^2), 
  0}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], r], 0, 0, -(1 + 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2)}}
```

furthermore I need the final expression only up to the order `c^-2`. I am using the code:

```
Simplify[Series[
  Series[Series[
    Series[Series[
      Series[Inverse[matr], {c, Infinity, 2}], {D[K[t, x, y, r], r], 
       0, 1}], {D[K[t, x, y, r], y], 0, 1}], {D[K[t, x, y, r], x], 0, 
     1}], {U[t, x, y, r], 0, 1}], {D[K[t, x, y, r], t], 0, 1}]]
```

The problem is that inevitably, there are terms of the type:

```
D[K[t,x,y,r],t]*D[K[t,x,y,r],x]
```

and so on.

Is it possible to tell Math. that those terms are small too, without adding them to the series?

Even better: how can I simplify my nested series expansion?

**EDIT**

To answer  @Daniel Lichtblau

The "small" terms must be at first order.

There are no problem in terms of the type `c.small=TooSmallToKeep`.

Comment: To what order will you retain "small" terms? And are there interactions with `c` that determine smallness e.g. `small*c==tooSmallToKeep`?

Comment: The small terms must be at first order, and no there are no problem like the ones you cited. I edit the post to explain it better

Comment: One way then is to write your matrix as mat=A+S where A is all regular terms or zeros and S is entirely small terms or zeros. A must be invertible and so mat=(I+SA^(-1))A where I is the identity matrix. The inverse, approximated to first order, can be now written as mat^(-1) is then A^(-1) (I - SA^(-1) + terms that get dropped). No need to use `Series` for this until you are ready to expand in `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factors $c^2$ should be no problem, so I'll focus on the question how we can tell *Mathematica* that all the functions are small. It boils down to introducing a bookkeeping parameter $\epsilon$ that is eventually set to $1$ after it has served its purpose of keeping track of powers of the small quantities:

```
replacementRule = {U :> (ϵ u[##] &), 
   K :> (ϵ k[##] &)};

matr = ReleaseHold[
   Hold[
     {{(1 - 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2 - 2*D[K[t, x, y, r], t]/c), -D[
         K[t, x, y, r], x], -D[K[t, x, y, r], y], -D[K[t, x, y, r], 
         r]}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], x], -(1 + 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2), 0, 
       0}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], y], 0, -(1 + U[t, x, y, r]/c^2), 
       0}, {-D[K[t, x, y, r], r], 0, 0, -(1 + 2*U[t, x, y, r]/c^2)}}
     ] /. replacementRule
   ];

Normal[Series[Inverse[matr], {ϵ, 0, 1}]] /. ϵ -> 
   1 // MatrixForm
```

[image: output]

the `replacementRule` takes your function names and replaces them with new functions (of the same number of arguments (`##`) using lower case names. But these new functions are multiplied by the parameter `ε`.

To do the replacement, I take your initial definition and wrap it in `Hold` so  the derivatives aren't done until the renaming has occurred, at which time `ReleaseHold` allows the evaluation. This is something you could of course also do by hand, but maybe not if your real application is larger.

Then the `Series` expansion requires only a **single** expansion, in terms of `ε`. You have to use `Normal` to convert the `SeriesData` object to a "normal" expression before finally setting `ε` to `1`.

This is closely related to the question [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15023/245), except that here we have to work with functions.