# Choosing a branch of the square root when performing a series expansion

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following problem. Consider expression

```
f=Sqrt[(x-2y)^2]
```

There is an obvious ambiguity in the definition of `f` related to multivaluedness of the square root. Two possible interpretations for `f` are $x-2y$ or $2y-x$.

My needs require to work with power series expansions of expressions like `f`. When asked to perform a series expansion *Mathematica* automatically chooses a branch

```
Series[f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Normal

(* -x + 2 y *)
```

I'm OK with that since I can adjust the sign of the square root manually and use `-f` instead of `f` if needed. The problem is that *Mathematica* is not consistent in her choice. For example, evaluate

```
Series[f, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal

(* x - 2 y *)
```

now it's the other branch!

In a real task I have a quite complicated function depending on many parameters under the square root. When I work with its series expansions naively, as described above, things just go wrong. How can the problem be handled?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: not clear what you are after. Do you want both expressions, or do you want a single result that is somehow consistent to you?  maybe an example of where this is a real issue would help

Comment: why is mathematica a "her" when it's doing something that is not consistent...is what I wonder

Answer (score 5):

I just saw this trick here http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m200/taylor2dSlides.pdf, page 2 and decided to try it on this problem. Another reference that describes this method is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67896/multivariate-taylor-series-derivation-2d

The idea is to convert multiple Taylor series in $x,y$ to one variable $t$ as follows

```
   f[t_] := Sqrt[((x0 + t x) - 2 (y0 + t y))^2];
```

Now $f(t)$ can be expanded in Taylor as single variable to avoid the issue at hand.

The trick is to set `t->1` afterwords and then take the limit of `x0->0` and `y0->0` since we are expanding around these which are zeros. Doing so, gives both solutions. Now depending on if we take the limit of `x0->0` or `y0->0` we get one of the solutions returned by Mathematica's Series!

But this way, you obtain both limits and then you can decide which one to use.

```
Clear[x0, t, x, y0, y]
f[t_] := Sqrt[((x0 + t x) - 2 (y0 + t y))^2];
r = Normal[Series[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]] /. t -> 1;
r = Simplify@Expand@ComplexExpand[%];
r = Limit[r, {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 0}]; %had to take limit 2 times to do it!
Limit[r, {y0 -> 0, x0 -> 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare the above to

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - 2 y)^2];
Normal[Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]] // Normal
(*-x + 2 y*)
Normal[Series[f[x, y], {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]] // Normal
(* x - 2 y *)
```

So, the single variable trick gives you both solutions. It seems Series takes the limit based on the order of the variables. Not sure about that. I can't explain exactly why Series did that, but I do not think it is a branch cut issue as you can see.

Comment: Similar approaches show up in MSE and related forums. See [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46533/multivariate-series-expansions-to-different-powers), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected), [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46659/nested-series-expansion), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747596/multivariate-taylor-series-expansion-in-mathematica) (there are probably others but I stop counting once I run out of thumbs).

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure how one might expect *Mathematica* to pick the "right" result, if getting the *possible* results gets you part way there. a simpler way to do this is:

```
mySeries[f_, p_] := DeleteDuplicates@(Normal@Series[f, Sequence @@ #] & /@ Permutations[p])

f = Sqrt[(x - 2 y)^2]
p = {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}
mySeries[f, p]

(* {-x + 2 y, x - 2 y} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

In M11.3+ giving [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) an [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option returns the outputs you want:

```
Series[f, {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}, Assumptions->x<2y] //Normal
Series[f, {y,0,1}, {x,0,1}, Assumptions->x<2y] //Normal
```

> -x + 2 y
>
> -x + 2 y

And with the opposite assumption:

```
Series[f, {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}, Assumptions->x>2y] //Normal
Series[f, {y,0,1}, {x,0,1}, Assumptions->x>2y] //Normal
```

> x - 2 y
>
> x - 2 y