# Series expansion not possible for more than two variables?

Tags: series-expansion

My problem is simple. I want to evaluate the series

```
Series[(1 + x*b - x*a)/(1 + 2*x*c - 2*x*a), {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {c, 
0, 2}].
```

Mathematica output looks like this:

[image: series]

The third variable (c) stays blue. The documentation claims that shouldn't be the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine and works well with V10.3.1, is the coloring your only concern? Does it work anyway? P.s. if you post a code one doesn't have to retype what is on the image...

Comment: I believe you'll find  [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15023/1871) interesting.

Comment: What happens if you evaluate that in a fresh kernel (that is, Quit[] and then make that the first evaluation afterward)?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a `Series`expansion or a Taylorpolynom of 2. degree?

With Mathematicas Series you get:

```
Series[(1 + x*b - x*a)/(1 + 2*x*c - 2*x*a), {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 2}] // Normal // Expand

1 + a x + b x - 2 c x + 2 a^2 x^2 + 2 a b x^2 - 6 a c x^2 - 
 2 b c x^2 + 4 c^2 x^2 + 4 a^2 b x^3 - 16 a^2 c x^3 - 8 a b c x^3 + 
 20 a c^2 x^3 + 4 b c^2 x^3 - 24 a^2 b c x^4 + 72 a^2 c^2 x^4 + 
 24 a b c^2 x^4 + 96 a^2 b c^2 x^5
```

With Taylor expansion:

```
taylor = (vars - point).# &;
init := D[f[vars], {vars, j}] /. Thread[vars -> point];
taylorPoly[m_] := Sum[1/j! Nest[taylor, init, j], {j, 0, m}]

vars = {a, b, c};
point = {0, 0, 0};
f[vars_] = (1 + x*b - x*a)/(1 + 2*x*c - 2*x*a);
taylorPoly[2] // Expand

1 + a x + b x - 2 c x + 2 a^2 x^2 + 2 a b x^2 - 6 a c x^2 - 2 b c x^2 + 4 c^2 x^2
```

or another method:

```
f[a_,b_,c_] = (1 + x*b - x*a)/(1 + 2*x*c - 2*x*a);
n = {a - a0, b - b0, c - c0};
grad = Grad[f[a0, b0, c0], {a0, b0, c0}];
hesse = D[f[a0, b0, c0], {{a0, b0, c0}, 2}];
taylor = f[a0, b0, c0] + n.grad + 1/2 n.hesse.n /. {a0 -> 0, b0 ->0, c0 -> 0} // Expand

1 + a x + b x - 2 c x + 2 a^2 x^2 + 2 a b x^2 - 6 a c x^2 - 2 b c x^2 + 4 c^2 x^2
```

As Kuba commented your code works fine in Mathematica 10.3.1