# Pertubation series of given equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to define a function that does the following.

If I have an equation, for example:

$$f(x)+[1-f^2(x)]+f^{\prime\prime}(x)+f(x)\ f^\prime(x)=0$$

and I am given a value for $f$ to expand about, say $\bar f$, I want the function to substitute $$f\rightarrow\bar f+\delta f$$ substitute it in the initial equation, and give me only the equation for $\delta f$, keeping terms up to order (given by me as argument $n$). For example, for $n=1$:

$$\delta f(x)+[1-\bar f^2(x)-2\bar f \delta f(x)]+\delta f^{\prime\prime}(x)+\bar f \delta f^\prime(x)=0$$

I usually do this by expanding with an $\epsilon$ in front of $f$ and then taking a series in $\epsilon$ small. At the end I impose $\epsilon=1$:

```
n = 1;
eq = f[x] + (1 - f[x]^2) + D[f[x], x, x] + f[x] D[f[x], x];
f[x_] = f0 + ϵ df[x];
eq1 = Normal[Series[eq, {ϵ, 0, n}]];
eqFin = eq1 /. ϵ -> 1 // FullSimplify
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, and how to embed all this in a function definition.

Summarising, the input would be:

- equation for $f$
- base state $\bar f$
- order of the expansion $n$

the output would be the new equation.

**Edit:**

I would also be interested in a generalisation to more than one variable and more than one function, for example in the case of a system of two coupled equations in `f[x,y]`, `g[x,y]` where both `f` and `g` need to be expanded up to order $n$.

Comment: At the very least, provide the complete desired result. And some code too ...

Comment: I added the desired result, and explained how I usually do it.

Comment: And also entered the code that does what I want, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, and how to embed all this in a function definition.

Comment: Related: [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15023/245)

Answer (score 5):

```
linearizeEquation[expr_, f_, fp_, order_] := Block[{e},
   Expand@Normal@Series[expr /. f -> (fp + e dF[#] &), {e, 0, order}] /. e -> 1
  ]
linearizeEquation[f[x] + (1 - f[x]^2) + D[f[x], {x, 2}] + f[x] D[f[x], x], f, f0, 1]
(* 1 + f0 - f0^2 + dF[x] - 2 f0 dF[x] + f0 dF'[x] + dF''[x] *)
```

Comment: Perturbation of order n?

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. It seems that the OP wants to vary the order of the expansion, not the order of the perturbation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, it looks like a perturbation to me. Bah, doesn't matter. +1

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. Thank you for the apathetic-pity-+1. :)

Comment: Hey! Cheer up! My apathy is a congenital disease.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius. *My* apathy is a contagious disease, but it's treatable.

Comment: I guess that `eq` should be `expr`, right?

Comment: @usumdelphini. Yes: I will fix it now.

Comment: Thanks, I would also be interested in a generalisation to more than one variable and more than one function, for example in the case of a system of two coupled equations in `f[x,y]`, `g[x,y]` where both `f` and `g` need to be expanded up to order $n$. Any idea? I can't see how to extend your code in order to work for these cases..