# Series expansion of a multivariable function to an order n for any number of variables

Tags: series-expansion, variable

Suppose I want to expand a multivariable function to an order `n`.

```
f1[x_, y_] = Sin[x + y];
Series[f1[x + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}] // Normal // Expand
```

> $x - x^3/6 + y - (x^2 y)/2 - (x y^2)/2 + (x^3 y^2)/12 - y^3/6 + (
>  x^2 y^3)/12$

So I have to eliminate terms like $x^3 y^2$. One way could be using `Exponent`.

```
series[f_Symbol, x_, y_, n_] := Module[{expn},
       expn = Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, n}, {y, 0, n}] // Normal // Expand;
       Total@Select[Level[expn, 1], (Exponent[#, x] + Exponent[#, y]) <= n &] 
      ]

series[f1, x, y, 3]
```

> $x - x^3/6 + y - (x^2 y)/2 - (x y^2)/2 - y^3/6$

- Is there any better way to do it?
- Can it be generalised for any number of variables?

By generalised I mean given a function, can the code detect the variables and make the expansion? I tried to use `Variables` but it does not work with trigonometric functions.

A related question might be [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: +1 It would be great if there were a built in function for this, or otherwise if it were possible to do `Series[f1[x + y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3 - x}]`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielLichtblau for the comment (and eyeopener :|). I can assure you there was no hidden intention behind the question.  Sometimes I stuck with simple questions just because I search the answer in wrong place :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to rescale x,y,... by s*x, s*y,... and expand around s:

```
series[f_, var : {_Symbol ..}, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{s},
  Expand@Normal[Series[ f /. Thread[ var -> (s var)], {s, 0, n}]] /. 
   s -> 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
series[f_, var : {_Symbol ..}, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{expr =
    Series[f, Sequence @@ ({#, 0, n} & /@ var)] //
      Normal // Expand},
  Select[expr, Total[Exponent[#, var]] <= n &]]

f1[x_, y_] = Sin[x + y];

series[f1[x, y], {x, y}, 3]

(*  x - x^3/6 + y - (x^2 y)/2 - (x y^2)/2 - y^3/6  *)

f2[x_, y_, z_] = z*Sin[x + y];

series[f2[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, 4]

(*  x z - (x^3 z)/6 + y z - 1/2 x^2 y z - 1/2 x y^2 z - (y^3 z)/6  *)
```