# Get the homogeneous part of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

What is the easiest or fastest way to extract the homogeneous part of a polynomial in Mathematica. For instance, if there were a function `homog_part[f,n]`, I could use it to extract the second, first and zeroth degree homogeneous part of $f=x^2+y^2+xy+x+y+7$ by writing `homog_part[f,2]` to get $x^2+y^2+xy$, `homog_part[f,1]` to get $x+y$ and `homog_part[f,0]` to get $7$.

I was thinking of using `Series`, but here you would give individual degrees of each variable while for the homogeneous part you need the total degree.

Comment: A question like this really should be accompanied by test input in cut-and-pasteable form.

Comment: @Daniel. Apologies. I agree. Some of the answer have these input so I will not add this in the question anymore. But I will keep this in mind for future reference/questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 + x y + x + y + 7;
homoPart = Total[Pick[MonomialList[#], Total[CoefficientRules[#][[All, 1]], {2}], #2]] &;
homoPart[f[x, y], #] & /@ Range[0, 3]
```

> {7, x + y, x^2 + x y + y^2, 0}

Answer (score 8):

`SeriesCoefficient` is useful for this. We just multiply all variables by a new variable and extract a degree term in that.

```
homogeneousPart[poly_, vars_, deg_] := 
 Module[{t}, 
  SeriesCoefficient[poly /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], {t, 0, deg}] /. 
   t -> 1]
```

Example:

```
pol = x^2 + y^2 + x*y + x + y + 7;

Table[homogeneousPart[pol, {x, y}, j], {j, 3, 0, -1}]

(* Out[6]= {0, x^2 + x y + y^2, x + y, 7} *)
```

Comment: +1 so neat. Nicer than all the manipulation I did with CoefficientRules :)

Comment: This is closely related to Jens's solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the link. I see that I upvoted that one. Should have realized this has come up before.

Answer (score 4):

```
hp[f_, n_] := 
 Total@Cases[{Plus @@ #1, #2 Inner[Power, Variables[f], #1, Times, 
        1]} & @@@ CoefficientRules[f], {n, w_} :> w]
```

e.g. `hp[f[x,y],#]&/Range[0,2]` yields `{7, x + y, x^2 + x y + y^2}`

or `hp[x^3 + 3 x^2 y + 2, #] & /@ Range[0, 3]` yields `{2, 0, 0, x^3 + 3 x^2 y}`