# Series doesn't seem to work on functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, function-construction

When you try to use the Multivariable option of Series, it doesn't work as intended, since it keeps terms of higher order than intended.

Example: Expand a two-variable gaussian exponential to second order.

```
In[1]:= f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
In[2]:= Normal[Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]]
Out[2]= 1 - y^2 + x^2 (-1 + y^2)
```

Here the last term is on fourth order. I found a solution to this here [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected).

Applying this to my problem yields this,

```
In[3]:= Normal[Series[f[x t, y t], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
Out[3]= 1 - x^2 - y^2
```

Which is the correct expansion to second order.

Now I intend to create a function to apply all the process in one step,

```
In[4]:=MultiSeries[exp_] := Module[{f},
f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[exp];
Normal[Series[f[x t, y t], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
]
```

The problem is that by doing that, it yields this,

```
In[5]:= MultiSeries[Exp[-x^2 - y^2]]
Out[5]= E^(-x^2 - y^2)
```

The problem doesn't seem to be on the compound expression since,

```
In[6]:= Clear[f]; f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2 - y^2]; Normal[Series[f[x t, y t], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1
```

Yields,

```
Out[6]= 1 - x^2 - y^2
```

This leads me to believe that the problem is in the Module function.
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It's a scoping issue involving the dummy pattern variables not being recognized as the "same" as the ones used in the input. A way to avoid this is to make the variables explicit in the `Module` input. Could do `multiSeries[exp_, vars_] := Module[{t},
  Normal[Series[exp /. Thread[vars -> t*vars], {t, 0, 2}]] /. t -> 1]` and try it on `multiSeries[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, y}]`.