# Dealing with positive power variables in Taylor expansion and assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, algebraic-manipulation, assumptions, order

I would like to compute the Taylor expansion of monomials whose powers are nonnegative rational variables.

First, here is a function which encodes the multivariate Taylor expansion at the points `pts`, at the order `ord` and with respect to the variables `var`.

```
mTaylor[expr_,var_List,pts_List,ord_Integer] /; Length[var] == Length[pts] := \
    Normal[(expr /. Thread[var -> s (var-pts)+pts]) + O[s]^ord] /. {s->1}
```

Assume I want to compute the multivariate Taylor expansion of the expression:

```
expr = x^a1 + x^a2 y^3
```

at the order $2$, wrt $(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ and where $a1,a2$ are nonnegative rationals.

The expected results would be

```
res = x^a1 (*=mTaylor[expr,{x,y},{0,0},3]*)
```

However I can't get my Taylor function correct to yield this result.

Even the case of integer powers is intricate.
I tried using global assumptions :

```
$Assumptions = Element[a1,NonNegativeIntegers] && Element[a2,NonNegativeIntegers]
```

I tried also to write a routine to remove the high order terms but again it doesn't seem it handles the assumptions on the power:

```
EliminTe[expr_,var_List,ordre_Integer]:=Module[{},\
      FromCoefficientRules[Select[CoefficientRules[expr, var], Refine[Total@#[[1]] <= ordre    ,Assumptions->Element[a2,NonNegativeIntegers]] &], var]]
```

---

Here is my code

```
mTaylor[expr_,var_List,pts_List,ord_Integer] /; Length[var] == Length[pts] := \
    Normal[(expr /. Thread[var -> s (var-pts)+pts]) + O[s]^ord] /. {s->1}

$Assumptions = Element[a1,NonNegativeIntegers] && Element[a2,NonNegativeIntegers]

expr = x^a1 + x^a2 y^3 

res = Refine[mTaylor[expr,{x,y},{0,0},3]]
```

Comment: If a1=10 and a2=1, is `x^a1` still the correct answer?

Comment: indeed, in such case it's not. I don't give specific values to a1 and a2. However I expect mathematica to understand that x^a2 y^3 is never in the expected result and x^a1 may or may not so he should keep it.

Comment: Is it correct that a more refined question would be "Why `s^(a+3)+O[s]^3` assuming `a > 0` won't simplify?"?

Comment: yes it is this point that my question is raising. Also I can change the implementation of the multivariate Taylor routine

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using the built in command `Series`?

Comment: Because it doesn't encode the true multivariate taylor expansion, see here :

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected