# Series vs Asymptotic in 12.1

Tags: series-expansion, language-design, function-comparison, asymptotics, version-12.1

The functionality of `Series` and `Asymptotic` (new in V12.1) is very similar. In fact, they are both listed in the [Asymptotics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Asymptotics.html) guide page. That same guide page hints that `Asymptotic` is more general than `Series`: while `Series` is just for functions, `Asymptotic` can handle integral transformations among other things.

This begs the question of when should one ever use `Series` if `Asymptotic` can apparently do everything `Series` could before? I remember this same question being raised during the development of V12.1, but I don't think it was ever really answered (term ordering and "propagation" of accuracy were mentioned). Now that V12.1 is out, has that changed? Is there something `Series` is better at than `Asymptotic`, or is `Asymptotic` going to supersede `Series`, which is now being kept for backwards compatibility only?

Answer (score 12):

*Extended comment, I won't accept this as an answer.*

---

Here are some cases I've found where `Series` might be a better choice than `Asymptotic`. This list doesn't show when `Asymptotic` could be better, since those cases are fairly well documented.

- **`Series` returns a `SeriesData` object, while `Asymptotic` returns a simple expression. Because of this, computations with the generated series is significantly easier with `Series`.**
- As an example of the previous point, exponentiating a series expansion gives more sensible results when using `Series`:

  ```
  Exp[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]]
  (* 1 + x + x^2/2 - x^4/8 - x^5/15 + O(x^6) *)

  Exp[Asymptotic[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}]]
  (* Exp[x - x^3/6 + x^5/120] *)
  ```
- Similarly, arithmetic operations with `SeriesData` automatically cuts off higher-order terms when needed. If I add two series, where one has five terms and the other only two, the resulting sum is also only second-degree, which is not what happens with `Asymptotic`:

  ```
  Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}] + Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}]
  (* 1 + x - x^2/2 + O(x^3) *)

  Asymptotic[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}] + Asymptotic[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}]
  (* 1 + x - x^2/2 - x^3/6 + x^5/120 *)
  ```
- Two series with different expansion centers cannot be combined with `Series`:

  ```
  Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 3}] + Series[Exp[x], {x, 1, 3}]
  (* Series in x to be combined have unequal expansion points 0 and 1 *)
  ```

  `Asymptotic` will, for better or for worse, happily combine them:

  ```
  Asymptotic[Exp[x], {x, 0, 3}] + Asymptotic[Exp[x], {x, 1, 3}]
  (* 1 + E/3 + x + (E x)/2 + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + (E x^3)/6 *)
  ```
- `Series` supports ["multivariate"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected) series expansions out-of-box, while `Asymptotic` does not:

  ```
  Series[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
  (* (y + O(y^3)) + x(1 - y^2/2 + O(y^3)) + x^2(-(y/2) + O(y^3)) + O(x^3) *)

  Asymptotic[Asymptotic[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 2}], {y, 0, 2}]
  (* x + y - (x^2 y)/2 - (x y^2)/2 *)
  ```
- `Asymptotic` is significantly slower for hypergeometric functions (and possibly other special functions):

  ```
  Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x], {x, Infinity, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
  (* {0.030965, ...} *)

  Asymptotic[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x], {x, Infinity, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
  (* {15.3086, ...} *)
  ```

  This may be a bug, as running `Series` with the new input notation `x->Infinity`

  ```
  Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x], x -> Infinity]
  ```

  runs for more than two minutes (didn't wait for completion, reported to WRI).

Comment: Many thanks for this Q&A.  But, why are there two separate functions for this?  I'm not particularly happy with this design choice.  The vast majority of analytic functions that scientists and engineers want to approximate have an asymptotic approximation that has the form exponential/trigonometric controlling factor times a Froebenius series.  `Series` already had that capability, and simply needed a refresh, and `SeriesData` can already accomodate Froebenius series.  The data structure could have been simply extended to include the controlling factor.

Comment: @QuantumDot Apologies if I have misunderstood your comment, but I wanted to clarify that I'm not involved with Wolfram, I'm just a random person interested in asymptotics, although I definitely agree with you. This "answer" is just from poking around and trying things and I really hope we get some more official clarification as to how these two are related, or why things wasn't implemented within `Series`. This should've absolutely been in the documentation.

Comment: It is indeed meaningless to combine expansions at locations in one expression. For multidimensional expansion x and y come into scope. It is too not so mathematical sense to have `SeriesTermGoal` with `Series`. `Series` is the Taylor expansion around a location on a polynomial basis up to a certain degree. Give a variable name or use `%` to work in the same way as with the `Series` symbol.

Comment: Series is definitely not the Taylor expansion.  Things like `Series[Zeta[x], {x, Infinity, 5}]` and `Series[BesselI[2, x], {x, Infinity, 5}]` are examples.

Comment: @Quantum, yes, `Series[]` can also do Puiseux series and expansions at infinity. imas: as user states, it is not quite sensible to combine different expressions with different expansion points, but of course you can add together the results of two `SeriesData[]` objects only after you use `Normal[]` on them to convert them into a finite sum.