# Series expansion of hypergeometric function with two variables

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I have a function $g(x,y)$ that contains a product of hypergeometric functions, both involving the variables $x$ and $y$. I try to do a series expansion in the two variables as recommended in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035/68480), however one of the two hypergeometrics does not get expanded. What can I do to avoid that?

[image]

The code:

```
g = (8 (1 + 2 s) (t x - I t y)^(2 + s) (t x + I t y) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -1 - s, -(1/2) - s, (t x + I t y)/(t x - I t y)] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 3 + s,7/2 + s, (t x - I t y) (t x + I t y)])/(1 + s);
Normal[Series[g, {t, 0, 6}]] /. t -> 1
```

(set $t$ to $1$ in order to retrieve the original function $g(x,y)$)

Comment: It's quite clear what happens by the way: the $t$ gets canceled in the argument of the hypergeometric function, maybe revealing a weak point of the answer linked above.

Comment: Do you really need an expansion around x=0 and y=0? There is no limit at this point, causing problems.

Comment: @CarlWoll How do you mean that? When I plot the function for some $s$ (those are integers by the way) it seems regular at $(0,0)$.

Comment: For example, the following limit is indeterminate `Limit[Hypergeometric2F1[
  1/2, -1 - s, -(1/2) - s, (t x + I t y)/(t x - I t y)], {x, y} -> {0,
    0}]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes true, one can see it also by setting either $x$ or $y$ to $0$. Let me think about it.