# Taylor expansion of expected value of a function with multiple random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics, series-expansion

The expected value of a function of multiple random variables can be approximated by a Taylor expansion. How this can be done in MMA is described in other posts ([Link1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035/69288), [Link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446573/269684)).

Let's assume we have a function of 3 iid normal variables

$f=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^4+x_3^4}$ with
$x_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma^2)$
and are looking for the expectation $\mathbb{E}[f]$.

The MMA code for a Taylor expansion of order 2 applying the cited descriptions would look like this:

```
f = Sqrt[(x[1] - x[2])^4 + x[3]^4]; (*our function*)
f = f /. x[i_] -> (z[i] - \[Mu][i]) t + \[Mu][i]; (*introduce dummy variable t*)
taylor = (Series[f, {t, 0, 2}] // Normal) /. t -> 1 // Expand;
mean = taylor //. z[i_]^2 -> \[Sigma]^2 + \[Mu][i]^2;
mean = FullSimplify[mean //. z[i_] -> \[Mu][i]]  (*output of 2nd order Taylor approximation*)
```

What is the reason to make the replacement in the form $z_i^2\to\sigma^2+\mu_i^2$ in the second last line, why is there an addition?

Comment: The expectation of $z_i^2$ is the sum of the variance ($\sigma^2$) and the square of the mean ($\mu_i^2).  Rather than performing the known integration one uses a replacement rule.

Comment: Your f expression in code an TeX are different. Also, would `TransformedDistribution` help here?

Comment: Just to make sure:  you do know that a large proportion of the values of $f$ could be imaginary?

Comment: example function f was corrected

Comment: If you just need a function within *Mathematica* to estimate the mean, then directly doing the numerical integration for the two random variables ($x_1-x_2$ and $x_3$ with the 3 parameters $\mu_1-mu_2$, $\mu_3$, and $\sigma$ is more accurate and just as quick as any Taylor expansion approach.  If you need a formula for use outside of *Mathematica*, then interpolation approaches might be feasible and more accurate than a Taylor expansion approach.  Is there a particular set of values for the parameters?

Comment: you are right, the given function f was only a too simple example, just assume that f would be more complex

Comment: I wrote it just a few minutes ago for me.
`(*function must be 1d*)
deltaApprox[f_, dist_] := Module[{moment, getDelta},
  moment[b_] := CentralMoment[dist, b];
  getDelta[g_, 
    mu_] := ((Table[D[g[x], {x, b}]/Factorial[b], {b, 0, 4}] /. 
       x -> (x + mu))) . Table[moment[b], {b, 0, 4}];
  getDelta[f, Mean@dist]
  ]`