# Asymmetric multivariable Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I want to expand a two-variable function up to asymmetric orders in two expansion variables, i.e.

$$f(x,y) = T[f(x,y)] + \mathcal{O}(x^2,y^3,xy,xy^2).$$

Note that, while quadratic terms in $y$ are retained, the (also!) quadratic terms in $xy$ are contained in the higher-order terms. Hence the asymmetry (and the ultimate origin of the problem).

The intuitive two-variable expansion

```
Series[f[x,y],{x,x0,1},{y,y0,2}]
```

includes some of the undesired terms, namely $xy$ and $xy^2$.

I've seen the (maybe) related post [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected). However, in this post the issue with the asymmetry in the two expansion variables is not commented, so the answers there are not directly applicable (in the best case).

Is there a simple way/function to perform this calculation?

Comment: Function `f[x,y]==-f[-x,y] ` is asymmetric in x?

Comment: Perhaps your question finds an answer if you tell us something about the relationship `O[x-x0]=?=O[(y-y0)^alfa] ,   alfa=2/3 or 3/2? or ...`?

Comment: In my problem there is no simple transformation rule for the function `f[x,y]` like the one you are metioning in your comment.

With respect to the orders of magnitude, you have approximately $\mathcal{O}(x) = \mathcal{O}(y^2)$, if that helps.

Comment: Why not compute all  terms and then replace the unwanted terms by zero?

Comment: Could modify the method in the related posts by weighting. I show this for the case of expansion at the origin. `In[28]:= Normal[
  Series[f[x, y] /. {x -> t^3*x, y -> t^2*y}, {t, 0, 4}]] /. t -> 1

Out[28]= f[0, 0] + y*Derivative[0, 1][f][0, 0] + 
   (1/2)*y^2*Derivative[0, 2][f][0, 0] + 
   x*Derivative[1, 0][f][0, 0]`

Comment: I should read responses more often. What I did is substantially similar to the method given by @UlrichNeumann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that `O[x-x0]==O[(y-y0)^2]` the taylor expansion follows to

```
Normal[Series[f[x, y] /. {x -> x0 + eps (x - x0),y -> y0 + eps^2 (y - y0)}, {eps, 0, 3}]] /. eps -> 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly as expected.