# Bilinearization with Mathematica - where to start?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, nonlinear

I tried to bilinearize the two equations:

```
eq = {Laplacian[psi[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     6 u[t, x, y] psi[t, x, y] + (x^2 + y^2) u[t, x, y] == 
    I D[u[t, x, y], 
      t], -(I /Sqrt[2] (D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[u[t, x, y], y]) + 
       psi[t, x, y]) == 1/10000 D[psi[t, x, y], t]};
```

and I have looked at some posts here on stackexchange, but found no posts that considered the matter of bilinearization. Does anyone have a tip of where to start?

```
nssm2 = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[eq, psi[t,x,y], u[t,x,y], t]
```

but to no avail.
I read also this:

https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Articles/2831/

But I couldn't find a hint there either.

Thanks

Comment: What means "bilinearization" ? `u & psi ` small from same order?

Comment: Yes, it means to get a linear form of the two PDEs where the two , u and psi, are part of the linearized resulting PDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
eq1=Normal[Series[eq /. {u -> Function[{t, x, y}, eps u[t, x, y]] ,psi -> Function[{t, x, y}, eps psi[t, x, y]]}, {eps,0,1}]] /.eps -> 1
```

to get the linearized two  odes !

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great start.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps solving your problem!

Comment: Yes, that last correction in your posts gave the right answer. It is in fact the same as Daniel Hubers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume that by "bilinearize" you mean linearization relative to u[t, x, y] and psi[t, x, y]. This can be achieved using `Series`. Note, `Series` relative to more than one variable does does first linearization relative to the first variable. Then, the result is linearized relative to the second variable, e.t.c. That means, we get cross terms, that need to be eliminated. E.g.

```
eq = {Laplacian[psi[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
     6 u[t, x, y] psi[t, x, y] + (x^2 + y^2) u[t, x, y] == 
    I D[u[t, x, y], 
      t], -(I /Sqrt[2] (D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[u[t, x, y], y]) + 
       psi[t, x, y]) == 1/10000 D[psi[t, x, y], t]};
```

To linearize, we do:

```
ser = Series[eq, {u[t, x, y], 0, 1}, {psi[t, x, y], 0, 1}];
```

This is a SeriesData object. For further work we need to get rid of the O[..] terms:

```
ser= ser // Normal;
```

To eliminate the cross terms, we first need to expand the expression and then set the cross terms to zero:

```
Expand[ser] /. u[t, x, y] psi[t, x, y] -> 0
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. If I linearize it with respect to the second variable, do I get 4 ODEs, which are all relevant?

Comment: ' Series[eq, {psi[t, x, y], 0, 1}] // Normal' gives 2PDE's

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Assuming you have an approximation $(u_k,\psi_k)$ then you can proceed linearly as

$$
\cases{
\mathcal{D}_1[u_{k+1}]+6(u_k \psi_k +u_k(\psi_{k+1}-\psi_k)+\psi_k(u_{k+1}-u_k))+(x^2+y^2)u_{k+1}=i \mathcal{D}_2[u_{k+1}]\\
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\mathcal{D}_3[u_{k+1}]+\psi_{k+1}=10^{-4}\mathcal{D}_4[\psi_{k+1}]
}
$$

solving for $(u_{k+1},\psi_{k+1})$ to obtain the next approximation. Here $\mathcal{D}_j[\cdot]$ are differential operators.

Answer (score 1):

[Look what @Jens has done:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected/15035#15035)

```
TaylorSeries[expr_, vars_?ListQ, start_?ListQ, order_?IntegerQ] := 
 Normal[Series[expr /. Thread[vars -> t*(vars - start) + start], {t, 0, order}]] /. t -> 1

eq = {Laplacian[psi[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 6 u[t, x, y] psi[t, x, y] + (x^2 + y^2) u[t, x, y] == 
I D[u[t, x, y], t], -(I/Sqrt[2] (D[u[t, x, y], x] + D[u[t, x, y], y]) + psi[t, x, y]) == 1/10000 D[psi[t, x, y], t]};

TaylorSeries[eq, {u[t, x, y], psi[t, x, y]}, {0, 0}, 1]
```

[image]