# Series expansion of a function up to linear terms

Tags: functions, series-expansion, approximation

I have the following:

```
\[CapitalSigma] = r^2 + a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2;
\[CapitalDelta] = r^2 - 2 M r + a^2 - k/3 r^2 (r^2 + a^2);
grr = \[CapitalSigma]/\[CapitalDelta];
```

and I want to obtain the expansion of `grr` up to linear terms in $M/r$ and $k r^2$. What I have done is to employ `Series` but I could not get the right answer which is
$$1+\frac{2M}{r}-\frac{kr^2}{3}$$
Does anyone have an idea as to what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: Why is there no dependence on `a`?

Comment: That also bothers me @CarlWoll, although the instruction is to expand up to linear terms in $M/r$ and $kr^2$ only

Comment: @CarlWoll, I am only expanding with respect to $r$ for large $r$.

Comment: Is the required true? `Limit[grr, r -> Infinity]` produces `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `k r^2, M/r, a/r` to be small of same order, expansion gives nearly the result you're expecting:

```
grr /. {M -> r eps M/r , k -> 1/r^2 eps k r^2,a -> r  eps a /r } // Simplify  
Normal[Series[%, {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1
(*1 + (2 M)/r + (k r^2)/3*)
```

Comment: Pay your attention to the minus sign   `- k r^2/3` in the required  expression.

Comment: What a pity, thanks.

Comment: Your solution helps @UlrichNeumann, although the sign of the third term "should" be negative.

Comment: Ok , I think you need to define the order of parameter `a` too. Otherwice it isn't possible to do the series expansion.