# Taylor expansion of binary function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := Log[1 + x + y]; Series[f[x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]
```

How to get this form:
x+y - 1/2 (x+y)^2+1/3 (x+y)^3+...

Comment: You get this in a expanded form. You may use "Normal" to get a polynomial.

Comment: `In[17]:= Normal[
  Series[Log[1 + x + y] /. Thread[{x, y} -> t*{x, y}], {t, 0, 3}]] /. 
 t -> 1

Out[17]= x + y - 1/2 (x + y)^2 + 1/3 (x + y)^3` It's pretty much covered in [this prior thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, knowing `x,y` to be small of equal order:

```
Normal[Series[Log[1 + eps (x + y)], {eps, 0, 3}]] /. eps -> 1
(*x + y - 1/2 (x + y)^2 + 1/3 (x + y)^3*)
```

Comment: Thanks. @Ulrich Neumann

Answer (score 3):

Use the definition of Taylor series for multiple variables function.

```
n = 3;
{x0, y0} = {0, 0};
taylor=Sum[1/i! Dot[D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, i}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> {x0,y0}], 
   Sequence @@ ConstantArray[{x, y} - {x0, y0}, i]], {i, 0, n}]//Expand
taylor==x+y - 1/2 (x+y)^2+1/3 (x+y)^3//Simplify
```

> `x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + y - x y + x^2 y - y^2/2 + x y^2 + y^3/3`

> `True`

Comment: Thank you.  @cvgmt