# How to tell Mathematica to leave only terms not higher than X power?

Tags: symbolic, syntax

Consider the following expression:

```
expr = a[x]*da[x,t]*db[x,t]c[x] + db[x,z]^2*a[x]^2*d[x] +d[x]^2*da[x,t]db[x,t]+ dc[x,z]^2 + c[x]*dc[x,z]^2*db[x,t]^6
```

Is there any way in Mathematica to leave only the terms with the total power of objects `#[x]` and `d#[x,#]` being $\leq 4$? The final expression should be

```
exprfinal = a[x]*da[x,t]*db[x,t]c[x] + d[x]^2*da[x,t]db[x,t] + dc[x,z]^2
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `Normal@Series[expr /. {factor : _[x] | _[x, t] | _[x, z] :> factor*$T}, {$T, 0, 4}] /. $T -> 1`?

Comment: That trick is from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 : exactly, thanks!

Comment: Please include the desired output from your expression as well.

Comment: I see this forum is starting to get the Math Stack Exchange downvoting disease.

Comment: @1729taxi This Q seems well-asked to me, but some of the other ones are not that good. This one's arguably a duplicate. But it took me a long time to find it, and I knew what I was looking for.

Comment: @MichaelE2 true but some people get downvoting disease. I don't know if you hang around Math Stack Exchange but it is a cesspit - with a core group of about ten people who basically feed off downvoting and sarcastic comments to brand new posters. This place isn't too bad for it - though I have seen an increase recently in such behaviour.

Comment: I’ve also noticed, with dismay, the uptick in downvotes. No idea why a question like this would warrant one.   It’s a duplicate, but (i) that’s far from obvious and (ii) there is a better way than downvoting to handle duplicates (those people at StackExchange, they think of everything).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I learned this trick from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035/4999):

```
Normal@Series[
  expr /. {factor : _[x] | _[x, t] | _[x, z] :> factor*$T},
  {$T, 0, 4}
  ] /. $T -> 1
```

The present question is framed in a different context than [Multivariable Taylor expansion does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15023/multivariable-taylor-expansion-does-not-work-as-expected), but the answer is the same to each.

On the other hand, if `expr` is a polynomial (as it is here), then the following approach works:

```
vars = Variables@expr;
deg = 4;
Fold[#1 . vars + #2 &, 
 Reverse@Take[CoefficientArrays[expr, vars], UpTo[deg + 1]]]
```

In many cases, such as if `expr` has a combination of parameters and variables, the user must supply an explicit list of variables.

Comment: (+1) Now I learned the trick with your answer! :-)

Comment: Thanks again! That's a super trick that simplifies my life a lot.

Answer (score 5):

There is now a resource function for this.

```
expr = a[x]*da[x, t]*db[x, t] c[x] + db[x, z]^2*a[x]^2*d[x] + 
   d[x]^2*da[x, t] db[x, t] + dc[x, z]^2 + 
   c[x]*dc[x, z]^2*db[x, t]^6;
vars = Variables[expr];

In[160]:= 
ResourceFunction["MultivariateTaylorPolynomial"][expr, vars, 4]

(* Out[160]= 
a[x] c[x] da[x, t] db[x, t] + d[x]^2 da[x, t] db[x, t] + dc[x, z]^2 *)
```