# How to extract specific terms from the polynomial?

Tags: symbolic, syntax, polynomials

Consider the following polynomial:

```
expr = (1 + a[x] + c[x, aa] + c[x, aa] da[x, aa] + 
 da[x, aa]*da[x, aa] + 
 dc[x, aa, bb]*da[x, cc]*da[x, bb]*eps[aa, bb, cc, dd])^3 //
```

Expand

Among all the terms, I want to leave only those which contain exactly three `a[x]` or `da[x,yy_]` and one `c` or `dc[x,yy_,zz_]`;  it is okay if they have `eps[aa,bb,cc,dd]`. At least one of the terms from `expr` matching these requirements is `3 a[x]^2 c[x, aa] da[x, aa]`.

Could you please tell me if this is possible in a more or less efficient way in Mathematica (in my realistic example, I deal with thousands of terms)?

**Edit**

This is my ugly realization. It uses [the following answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288460/how-to-tell-mathematica-to-leave-only-terms-not-higher-than-x-power):

```
ruleFixedPower[expr_, field_, dfield_, n_] := (Normal@
     Series[expr /. {factor : 
          field[x] | field[x, a_] | dfield[x, a_] | 
           dfield[x, a_, b_] :> factor*$T}, {$T, 0, n}] /. {$T -> 
      1}) - (Normal@
     Series[expr /. {factor : 
          field[x] | field[x, a_] | dfield[x, a_] | 
           dfield[x, a_, b_] :> factor*$T}, {$T, 0, 
       Max[0, n - 1]}] /. {$T -> 1})
```

Then,

```
expr1 = ruleFixedPower[expr, a, da, 3];
expr2 = ruleFixedPower[expr1, c, dc, 1]
```

> 6 a(x) da(x,bb) da(x,cc) dc(x,aa,bb) eps(aa,bb,cc,dd)+6 a(x) c(x,aa) da(x,aa)^2+3 a(x)^2 c(x,aa) da(x,aa)+6 c(x,aa) da(x,aa)^3

Unfortunately, it is slow as hell for my realistic tasks with many thousands of terms and more than two different structures, the powers of which have to be fixed. I may pre-select to have only the terms with the total degree equal to `n`, where `n` is the total degree of the desired output, but still, it is slow.

The derivative expansion would work much faster than this construction with `Series`, but it obviously introduces wrong expansion coefficients.

To illustrate the slowness, consider the following expansion:

```
expr = (1 + a[x] + c[x, aa] + a[x]*b[aa] + c[x, aa]* da[x, aa] + 
      dc[x, bb] dx[x, dd] + da[x, aa]*da[x, aa] + 
      dc[x, aa, bb]*da[x, cc]*da[x, bb]*eps[aa, bb, cc, dd])^16 // 
   Expand;
expr // Length
```

> 167637

```
(*Selecting terms not with the common power not higher than n*)
ruleCommonPower[expr_, 
  n_] := (Normal@
    Series[expr /. {factor : 
         a[x] | ca[x, a_] | da[x, a_] | dc[x, a_, b_] :> 
        factor*$T}, {$T, 0, 14}] /. {$T -> 1})
expr0 = ruleCommonPower[expr, 14]; // AbsoluteTiming
expr1 = ruleFixedPower[expr0, a, da, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
expr2 = ruleFixedPower[expr1, c, dc, 4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This code gets stuck.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expression for the expected result.

Comment: @BobHanlon : I have provided the desired output together with my (very slow) solution for this problem.

Comment: It is not clear how the terms of the shown desired output satisfies the requirement of "contain exactly three a[x] or da[x,yy_] and one dc[x,yy_,zz_]"

Comment: For `ruleFixedPower`, you ought to be able to use `SeriesCoefficient` and avoid subtracting two series.

Comment: This is very confusing. In the description there is mention of `a[x], da[x,yy_] , dc[x,yy_,zz_]` but the putative term then given, `3 a[x]^2 c[x, aa] da[x, aa]`, has no `dc[...]`, contrary to the requirement that there be exactly one (I assume this counting is by multiplicity). Before tackling this I'd want to see the actual objective in unambiguous terms.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : excuse me, I have modified the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can create artificial powers in a new variable and then extract only those of interest from the expanded form. For this example we want to have exactly 3 of one type of variable and exactly 1 of another. We can take use `E` in the exponents of the first type, and integers for the second. Then we are seeking powers of `1+3*E`.

```
expr = (1 + a[x] + c[x, aa] + c[x, aa] da[x, aa] + 
     da[x, aa]*da[x, aa] + 
     dc[x, aa, bb]*da[x, cc]*da[x, bb]*eps[aa, bb, cc, dd])^3;

powers = {E, E, 1, 1};
reps = Thread[{a[x], da[x, yy_], dc[x, yy_, zz_], c[x, yy_]} -> 
    t^powers*{a[x], da[x, yy], dc[x, yy, zz], c[x, yy]}];

e2 = Expand[expr] /. reps;
terms = Cases[e2, t^(1 + 3*E)*aa_ :> aa]

(* Out[213]= {3 a[x]^2 c[x, aa] da[x, aa], 6 a[x] c[x, aa] da[x, aa]^2, 
 6 c[x, aa] da[x, aa]^3, 
 6 a[x] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, dd]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks very elegant, and it may be extended to an arbitrary sets of variables.

Comment: Thanks again! It works fantastically fast.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if the following selection meets your demand, but its the way to implement such sieves

```
   Select[expr, ( Count[#, _a | _da] == 3 && Count[#, _d | _dc] == 1 &)]   

     6 a[x] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, dd] + 
         6 a[x] c[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] 
           eps[aa, bb, cc,dd] +
         6 c[x, aa] da[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] 
       eps[aa, bb, cc, dd] + 
         6 c[x, aa]^2 da[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, dd] + 
         6 a[x] da[x, aa]^2 da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb]  bb, cc, eps[aa,dd]
```

Eventually  one has to check for the count of additional features as integer multiples, integer powers or

```
    Count[#,pattern,depth]
```

or specifying the variables pattern inside the given functions a by

```
 Count[#, a[x]|a[y],Infinity]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with pattern matching. The pattern will be complicated and needs to be protected against evaluation by "HoldPattern".

Then we will first search for terms with 3 a or da by the pattern:
"___   (a[x] | da[x, _])  ___  (a[x] | da[x, _])  ___  (a[x] | da[x, _])  ___":

```
tmp = Cases[expr, 
  HoldPattern[___   (a[x] | da[x, _])  ___  (a[x] | 
      da[x, _])  ___  (a[x] | da[x, _])  ___]];
```

Then with search the results for c or dc by the pattern: "___ (c | dc[x, _, _]) ___":

```
Cases[tmp, HoldPattern[___ (c | dc[x, _, _]) ___]]

{6 a[x] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, dd], 
 6 a[x] c[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, 
   dd], 6 c[x, aa] da[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa,
    bb, cc, dd], 
 6 a[x] c[x, aa] da[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, 
   bb, cc, dd], 
 6 c[x, aa]^2 da[x, aa] da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, 
   cc, dd], 
 6 a[x] da[x, aa]^2 da[x, bb] da[x, cc] dc[x, aa, bb] eps[aa, bb, cc, 
   dd]}
```